# Confused with javascript innerText property

Tags: javascript, html, innertext

I am getting confused with javascript innerText property. How does exactly it works?

```
  let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
  console.log('Confused', h1);
  let h11 = document.querySelector('h1');
  console.log('Confused', h11);
  h1.innerText = 'Inserted';
  console.log('Got it', h1);
```

- I could understand that h1 and h2 both contain the same node that why inserting text in h1 node cause changes both h1 and h11.
- But I could not understand that why both of this h1 and h11 get inserted at line 2 and 4 (Markdown as confused inside console). Although I inserted at the end of the code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not my question. My question is I could not understand that why both of this h1 and h11 get inserted at line 2 and 4 (Markdown as confused inside console). Although I inserted at the end of the code?

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: From the looks of it, at least in Google Chrome's implementation, there appears to be a time lag between console.log being called and it being executed. When I wrapped the console log within a timeout (0ms) I still got "Inserted." When I set a timeout of 50ms it showed the original h1. Also, when I used Chrome's debugger to execute each line one at a time, only the last console.log showed "Inserted"

Comment: innerText is not a javascript property, it's a `HTMLElement` object property

Comment: the output of objects in `console.log` is not static - it's evaluated when you inspect the content ...

Comment: try this ... `var x = {}; console.log(x); x.a=1;` ... now expand the seemingly empty x object logged in the console

Comment: @Kei - no. In chrome, see the blue `i` when you "open" the object? hover over it - it says *"value below was evaluated justnow"* - i.e. basically shows what I was saying in my comment

Comment: @Jaromanda X, with objects, yes, but I believe Chrome's console.log treats HTML element differently. For elements the console.log shows the HTML of the element being logged.

Comment: And err regarding my previous comment, I apologize, I meant wrapping the `h1.innerText = 'Inserted'` in a timeout, not the console.log.

Comment: @Kei - no, this "behaviour" is nothing to do with the fact that the object logged is a html element - try the code in my comment

Comment: @Jaramada X, yes I understand your point. However, OP is not referring to inspecting the contents of the object being logged. He is referring to the initial *text* that console.log displays prior to inspection. Actually, with your code it's rather interesting. The initial *text* of the console.log shows {}. Of course, if you inspect it, it will show that the contents have been updated. Subsequent console.log(x) will have an initial text of {a: 1}. With OP's example the initial text shows `Confused <h1>Inserted</h1>`. Try running OP's code with and without the h1.innerText wrapped in a timeout.

Comment: @JaromandaX Your previous comment (```var x = {}; console.log(x); x.a=1;```) really makes me confused. I thought @kei was right (There is a time lag between execution and console.log called).

Comment: @Kei - I use firefox, so it doesn't look confusing at all

Comment: @JaromandaX could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @JaromandaX ah okay, on Firefox it just shows the <h1> which you can expand to view its contents. On Chrome, it will show you the full HTML of the <h1>.

Comment: @BiswajitBiswas - I can't explain it more than I have

Comment: @Kei - in my chrome it logs `<h1>...</h1>`

Comment: @JaromandaX does it not look like [this](https://i.screenshot.net/0nwyxtv)?

Comment: @Kei, only once I click on `<h1>` - as I said, it looks *literally* like `<h1>…</h1>`

Comment: @JaromandaX hmm, interesting. On mine the full h1 shows up from the beginning.

Comment: Don't forget to check out MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to understand what is happening, you can use this illustration
run this snippet in your console

```
let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
console.log('Confused', h1);
let h11 = document.querySelector('h1');
console.log('Confused', h11);
console.log('Got it', h1);
```

This is without the `h1.innerText = 'Inserted';` and observe the values of the `h1` and the `h11`.

and then run this

```
h1.innerText = 'Inserted';
```

And observe the values of the `h1` and the `h11` again in the console. You will realize that they have been updated to the same thing with `innerText` to be `Inserted`.

Now run this

```
let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
console.log('Confused', h1);
let h11 = document.querySelector('h1');
console.log('Confused', h11);
h1.innerText = 'Inserted';
console.log('Got it', h1);
```

Observe that the final result is what you got after running `h1.innerText = 'Inserted';`
Now what is happening?
`JavaScript variables are containers for storing data values.`
You see variables are just containers for storing data. Before the line `h1.innerText = 'Inserted';` comes up they had the content you expected them to have but when that line runs their content changes and you get what you are observing. The problem is that this happens so fast that you don't see the first versions of `h1` and `h11` and only see their updated versions, because in reality they are just containers for storing data and not data themselves, or you can refer to them as `the name of a storage location`